# Why npx create-react-app gives npm error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

npx create-react-app bookstore

this command give error like in image:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaH6f.jpg):

can anyone help me to create-react-app

I try re-installing node version and also give environment variable path and again same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I used latest version of node but npm version is minor so I upgrade my npm version to execute below command:
npm update @latest
Or
ncu --upgrade

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when attempting to perform the task within a Google Drive folder. I recommend trying it in a different folder instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, issues can arise due to a corrupted npm cache. Try clearing the npm cache by running the following command:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

If the enoent error persists, try using npm instead of npx to create the React app:

```
npm init react-app myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that error indicates that you have not installed npm. You need to visit nodejs website and install nodejs for your computer. After that, make sure you have the latest version downloaded: node --version. Then try running the command again.